# Exchange certificate questions

Tags: windows, exchange, exchange-2007, certificate, outlook-web-app

I got the following message `The STARTTLS certificate will expire soon`. Now I tried to create new certificates, but currently the old ones are still used.

Questions:

- Can I backup the old certificate somehow (in case I remove one but missed a thing)?
- Does a service can be assigned to only one certificate? (I always get the notice that another certificate is getting priority) And can I delete the other one with the same assigned service?
- Can I delete certificates with the status `DateInvalid`?
- Can I delete certificates with no services assigned?

Now the certificates which have to be replaced.

**Case 1:**

Old one:

```
AccessRules        : {System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule, System
                     .Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule, System.Securi
                     ty.AccessControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule}
CertificateDomains : {Sites, servername.domain.local}
HasPrivateKey      : True
IsSelfSigned       : False
Issuer             : CN=domain-servername-CA
NotAfter           : 24.08.2012 08:55:23
NotBefore          : 25.08.2010 08:55:23
PublicKeySize      : 2048
RootCAType         : Registry
SerialNumber       : 486D0BC600000000500C
Services           : IIS, SMTP
Status             : Valid
Subject            : CN=Sites
Thumbprint         : 5XY3E4589CDEE54C1FB9C1745XC351D8C74D
```

Replacement:

```
AccessRules        : {System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule, System
                     .Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule, System.Securi
                     ty.AccessControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule, System.Security.Acce
                     ssControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule}
CertificateDomains : {Sites, servername.domain.local}
HasPrivateKey      : True
IsSelfSigned       : True
Issuer             : CN=Sites
NotAfter           : 30.07.2017 12:41:34
NotBefore          : 30.07.2012 12:41:34
PublicKeySize      : 2048
RootCAType         : None
SerialNumber       : AAFC94772E6BFF8E4AE9812226240927
Services           : IIS, SMTP
Status             : Valid
Subject            : CN=Sites
Thumbprint         : 98732EASYDFGC4336430DEDE729EE0D575C0
```

Notable differences:

- self signed is true
- issuer is different
- two times: System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule

**Case 2:**

Old one:

```
AccessRules        : {System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule, System
                     .Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule, System.Securi
                     ty.AccessControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule}
CertificateDomains : {mail.domain.com, many further domains}
HasPrivateKey      : True
IsSelfSigned       : False
Issuer             : CN=servername-domain-CA
NotAfter           : 17.08.2012 15:37:50
NotBefore          : 18.08.2010 15:37:50
PublicKeySize      : 2048
RootCAType         : Registry
SerialNumber       : 56329D6600000000000D
Services           : IMAP, POP, SMTP
Status             : Valid
Subject            : CN=mail.domain.com, OU=Technics, O=Organisation, L=Location, C
                     =CC
Thumbprint         : A8329DCD493FLIE2E3C9AF2E7577ADD6EF669
```

Replacement:

```
AccessRules        : {System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule, System
                     .Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule, System.Securi
                     ty.AccessControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule, System.Security.Acce
                     ssControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule}
CertificateDomains : {mail.domain.com, many further domains}
HasPrivateKey      : True
IsSelfSigned       : True
Issuer             : C=CC, L=Location, O=Organisation, OU=Technics, CN=mail.domain
                     .com
NotAfter           : 30.07.2017 12:17:33
NotBefore          : 30.07.2012 12:17:33
PublicKeySize      : 2048
RootCAType         : None
SerialNumber       : A9A4E319D016B296488457C8FB7DF8B7
Services           : IMAP, POP, SMTP
Status             : Valid
Subject            : C=CC, L=Location, O=Organisation, OU=Technics, CN=mail.domain
                     .com
Thumbprint         : 83EKDFKLIO483ZH94F2C84B7DA16DC3C05875D
```

Notable differences:

- self signed is true
- issuer is different
- two times: System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule
- order of subject is different

Now my question to these certificates:

- Can I ignore the differences?
- For the replacements: Can I delete the old certificates and all would still work (e.g. Outlook Web Access)?

Answer (score 1):

For Exchange 2007, you can use this tool from U-BTech to manager your certificates. They have a screen-shot guide.
http://www.u-btech.com/products/certificate-manager-for-exchange-2007.html

To answer your question:

1. Can you ignore the differences > NO.
2. Can you delete the old Cert > You shouldn't delete the old-cert from a third-party provider and replace it with a self-signed cert.

You would want to keep the cert which has IsSelfSigned: False for TLS to work.
Also, you will have to renew the Third-party issued certificate from the cert-provider for the "Old One", as it's expiring in a week's time.

PS: You shouldnt post your Cert Serial and Thumbprint on the Tubes :)